# hyperledger:Error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable Usage: peer channel create [flags]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

```
root@bq4_node1:/opt/fabric/bin# $FABRIC_ROOT/bin/peer channel create -o orderer.local:7050 -f $FABRIC_CFG_PATH/channel-artifacts/channel.tx -c mychannel -t 30 --tls true --cafile $ordererCa
```

> `Error: Error connecting due to  rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable
>   Usage:
>     peer channel create [flags]`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Although, not very clear what exactly you are trying to do, I would guess it's somehow related to the channel creation and joining a new peer to that channel.

First of all please take a look on Hyperledger Fabric documentation and tutorial on [Writing Your First Application](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html). There is also "[Building Your First Network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html)", also make sure you have followed [Prerequisites](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html).

You need to start with creating crypto material for your network entities: peer and ordering service, you can leverage `cryptogen` tool to receive root CA keys and signed certificates for peers and users. Here is the example of `crypto-config.yaml`, which will allow to generate orderer organization related crypto material as well as for two peers organizations:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org2: See "Org1" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

You can use `cryptogen` to generate results:

```
cryptogen generate --config=crypto-config.yaml --output=.
```

Next, you can use `configtxgen` to create configuration transaction which will allow to produce genesis block and create the channel, [here an additional example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/first-network/configtx.yaml). Command line command:

1. Generate genesis block for ordering service:

   ```
   FABRIC_CFG_PATH=. configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock genesis.block
   ```
2. Generate config transaction to create new channel:

   ```
   FABRIC_CFG_PATH=. configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -channelID mychannel -outputCreateChannelTx=mychannel.tx
   ```

Finally you can use peer cli command to create a new channel as you have tried in your question:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.local:7050 -f mychannel.tx -c mychannel -t 30 --tls true --cafile $ordererCa
```

Also please make sure that `orderer.local` is the host name of the available ordering service and also environmental variables for endorsing peers correctly configured and peer is running.